# Monitoring several remote servers over different VPNs

Tags: vpn, monitoring

I'm a developer with about 20 different clients running our server application. I access each of the clients' servers remotely through VPN to provide support, updates, etc.

Is there any tool available that I can set up locally that will connect through each of the VPNs automatically to allow me to monitor?

The idea sounds very far fetched to me as the VPN software varies a good bit but maybe someone's had to do something similar before?

It's been a few years since I last used Nagios but I think it'd be quite cool to have that set up pointing at each of the remote servers through VPN somehow.

Answer (score 3):

We do this with our clients systems.
Openvpn or ipsec for the connection.
Nagios as monitoring server at our office and nsclient++ on remote servers.
We use actually a mix of snmp and nsclient++ check.
But for some slow connection i find nsclient++ much better

Comment: Sounds promising. Thanks a million. Will try this setup tomorrow

Comment: Follow up: As I know nothing at all about VPN, what changes are we talking about making on the server? For example, one client uses SonicWall. Will I be able to use OpenVPN or IPSec without any changes?

Comment: Ipsec is a standard so no problem if the firewall/router supports it.
SSL vpn are not a standard so normally it's advised to make ssl vpn between different appliance. If you install an openvpn server beyond the firewall/router than you solved all the problems.

Comment: Sorry...i was meaning "it's not advised"